# Is it always better to use F1-Score than Accuracy as performance metric?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy, metric

During reading papers about Machine Learning I always find researchers using accuracy as their sole performance metric. However, a high accuracy alone proves nothing when the amount of false positives and false negatives are wide apart: https://tryolabs.com/blog/2013/03/25/why-accuracy-alone-bad-measure-classification-tasks-and-what-we-can-do-about-it/

So why do people still use it despite its obvious disadvantages?
Why not just use F1 score?